# I have a "removed" question which I didn't ask

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have just noticed that there is a question that is associated with my account that has since been removed ["Qn. about alexa rankings"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16297663/qn-about-alexa-rankings) asked 11:56 Saturday 02 June 2013. I didn't create the question.

Any idea what could have happened?

Answer (score 2):

You [edited this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16297663/edit), which probably got you 2 rep for it. Given that the question has now been removed, this rep is taken back.

Comment: Ah got it! I can't see any information about the question as it's been removed. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. There is a revision by @KevinBrydon on the question.

Comment: @Oded I understand now. You guys must have privileges to see deleted questions

Comment: @KevinBrydon - +10k users and the original asker can see deleted questions.

Comment: @KevinBrydon I think you should be able to see the same link as I've put into my answer. That's a bit of a work-around though.

Comment: @Bart Yep I can see it now. Thanks

Comment: @Oded +10k users, diamond moderators and the original asker regardless of their reputation. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Didn't think I needed to mention diamond mods ;)

Comment: Oh SURE @Oded, that's how it starts. Plain and simple moderator abuse. Don't mention one thing, forget to mention another, make things all vague for us regular users, moderators gone wild with their abuse and things and stuff. (Did I mention "things"?) You know what started exactly like this?!? That's right ..... */me goes off on some weird tangential rant even I don't understand, never to be heard from again, wondering if "moderators gone wild" would make a marketable video series* :)

Comment: @Bart - I was reading through waiting for Godwin's law to make an appearance ;)